# Hillis & Steele: Kernel Function

Tags: cuda, gpu

Can someone help to understand how the Hillis & Steele: Kernel Function work for each thread execution?

```
__global__ void scan(float *g_odata, float *g_idata, int n)
 {
    extern __shared__ float temp[]; // allocated on invocation
    int thid = threadIdx.x;
    int pout = 0, pin = 1;
    // load input into shared memory.
    // This is exclusive scan, so shift right by one and set first elt to 0
    temp[pout*n + thid] = (thid > 0) ? g_idata[thid-1] : 0;
    __syncthreads();
    for (int offset = 1; offset < n; offset *= 2)
    {
      pout = 1 - pout; // swap double buffer indices
      pin = 1 - pout;
      if (thid >= offset)
        temp[pout*n+thid] += temp[pin*n+thid - offset];
      else
        temp[pout*n+thid] = temp[pin*n+thid];
     __syncthreads();
    }
    g_odata[thid] = temp[pout*n+thid1]; // write output
}
```

Since now I have understand the following: Firstly, we have `pout=0, pin=1 and thid = [1,bockDim.x]`.
So until the first synchronization we have a simple shift to the right, e.g if we had the array `[1 | 2 | 5 | 7 ]` the new array is `[0 |1 | 2 | 5 | 7 ]` .

I consider the execution of the `for loop` as multiple instances, each instance for each `thId`. For example, if `thId=0` we are going to have the following execution:

1. `thid=0`

   - `offset=1`
   - pout = 1-0=1 (*use of the pout initialization at the beginning of the function*)
   - pin = 1 - 1 =0; (*use pout that is just computed, e.i 1*)
   - temp[4] = temp[0] (*else statement*)
   - [0 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 0]
   - `offset=2`
   - pout = 1-1=0 (*use pout from the previous step in loop*)
   - pin = 1 - 0 =1; (*the just computed value*)
   - temp[0] = temp[4] (*else statement*)
   - [0 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 0]

   The pout and pin variables are changed based on the information inside for loop and not
   considering the initialization of these variables at the beginning. With the same way
   I imagine the execution for `thid=1`.
2. `thid=1`

   - `offset=1`
   - pout = 1 - 0 = 1 (*use of the pout initialization at the beginning of the function*)
   - pin = 1 - 1 = 0
   - temp[4+1] =  temp[0+1-1] (*if statement*) ???? **memory out bounds in temp** ????

Can anybody give an intuitive example of how that it is executed? Also when the last code statement is going to be executed which value of pout is going to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean parallel scan algorithm, you could see here for an intuitive explanation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum

[image]

And I believe these links also help.

http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_scan.html

http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_scan.html

http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/namespacecub.html#abec44bba36037c547e7e84906d0d23aba0fa6cac57b7df2f475a67af053b9371c

Comment: Hello Eric. Thank you for answering. Very interesting links but basically I am interesting in understanding this example not because I need scan but because I want to understand how the thread execution works in this simple example, before using something more complicated. I had tried to do a diagram of the code example like the one you pasted for the specific snippet but I found some difficulties. I would be thankful if you could give me an example like the one I have tried to do above but I met a dead end. Thank you again for the answer your help is always useful.

Comment: Thinks are more clear now having attend [web courses](https://www.coursera.org/course/hetero) and reading some book chapters. Sorry, for my delay response I was a little in active on the forum. I consider your post useful so I mark it as answered.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this has been 5 years now. Nevertheless, I want to answer this question as I just spent some time myself to figure this out. Maybe this still helps someone...

1. Regarding the "memory out of bounds in temp": You need to allocate twice as much shared memory as your input array `g_idata` has.
2. In my opinion, the code needs to be changed slightly in order to work. I attached a working example. Compile with `nvcc -std=c++11`.

https://github.com/fg91/learning_cuda/blob/master/notes/lesson_3/scanHillisSteele.cu

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

__global__ void scanHillisSteele(int *d_out, int *d_in, int n) {
  int idx = threadIdx.x;
  extern __shared__ int temp[];
  int pout = 0, pin = 1;

  temp[idx] = (idx > 0) ? d_in[idx - 1] : 0;
  __syncthreads();

  for (int offset = 1; offset < n; offset *= 2) {
    // swap double buffer indices
    pout = 1 - pout;
    pin = 1 - pout;
    if (idx >= offset) {
      temp[pout*n+idx] = temp[pin*n+idx - offset] + temp[pin*n+idx];  // changed line
    } else {
      temp[pout*n+idx] = temp[pin*n+idx];
    }
    __syncthreads();
  }
  d_out[idx] = temp[pout*n+idx];
}

int main() {
  const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
  const int ARRAY_BYTES = ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(int);

  // generate the input array on the host
  int h_in[ARRAY_SIZE]{1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15, 19};
  int h_out[ARRAY_SIZE];

  // declare GPU memory pointers
  int * d_in;
  int * d_out;

  // allocate GPU memory
  cudaMalloc((void **) &d_in, ARRAY_BYTES);
  cudaMalloc((void **) &d_out, ARRAY_BYTES);

  // transfer the array to the GPU
  cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, ARRAY_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // launch the kernel
  scanHillisSteele<<<1, ARRAY_SIZE, 2 * ARRAY_BYTES>>>(d_out, d_in, ARRAY_SIZE);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  // transfer the resulting array to the cpu
  cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, ARRAY_BYTES, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  // print out the input and resulting array
  std::cout << "Input:" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
    std::cout << h_in[i] << " " << std::flush;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl << "Exclusive scan with operation +:" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
    std::cout << h_out[i] << " " << std::flush;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // free GPU memory allocation
  cudaFree(d_in);
  cudaFree(d_out);

  return 0;
}
```